# Gstreamer cant play stream from other pc: h264->rtp->udp

Tags: udp, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I want to stream a h264 video over UDP to another pc.
I am using this pipeline to produce the stream:
`videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=400,height=400,framerate=7/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=nal ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=2705`

I can play this on the same machine (with ip address 192.168.1.100) with this pipeline:
`udpsrc port=2705 ! application/x-rtp,width=400,height=400,encoding-name=H264,payload=96,framerate=7/1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink`

But when I try to stream it from another pc to the same machine I get only this output and it waits forever:
*Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...

Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...

New clock: GstSystemClock

Redistribute latency...

Redistribute latency...*

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. A videoconvert element is needed in the playing pipeline.
The working playing pipeline is:

`udpsrc port=2705 ! application/x-rtp,width=400,height=400,encoding-name=H264,payload=96,framerate=7/1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`